# How to create dropdown in laravel

Tags: laravel

i want dropdown of one column in Laravel, for creating it should display all nations in drop-down, for update purpose current nation should be selected.
any example or tutorial would be helpful thanks.
**My Try:**

```
<select name="nation" class="custom-select" >
      <option selected value="">Choose...</option>
      <option value="{{@$teacher->nation}}"  {{@$teacher->nation== "Pakistan" ? 'selected' : ''}} >{{@$teacher->nation}}</option>
      </select>
```

**Problem:** my dropdown is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="nation" class="custom-select">
    <option selected value="">Choose...</option>
    @foreach($teachers as $teacher)
        <option value="{{ $teacher->nation }}"  {{ $teacher->nation == "Pakistan" ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{ $teacher->nation }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dropdown structure in laravel

```
 <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="role_id">
    @if($roles->count() > 0)
        @foreach($roles as $role)
        <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->name}}</option>
        @endForeach
    @else
        No Record Found
    @endif   
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select name="nation" class="custom-select" >
     <option value="">Choose...</option>
        @foreach ($teachers as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('nation') == $key ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $value }}</option>
        @endforeach
 </select>
```